# Why get Warning "Unknown tag" in Eclipse for Vaadin Elements

Tags: html, eclipse, vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-designer

I use Eclipse with Vaadin 8 and Vaadin Designer. In the Source mode view of the Vaadin designer, i get warning for all my Vaadin Elements. It is not a problem for the system but it is annoying to see these warnings all the time. I have added a shreenshot. How do I resolve these warnings?

[image: unknown Tag]

Comment: I guess you have to contribute your patch for that here: https://github.com/vaadin/eclipse-plugin

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is just right click the editor and go preferences / web / validation. Select what you want to do with "Unknown tag name", e.g. ignore. You can set this for specific project, if you need html validation in other projects.

[image]